# setInterval - not working as expected with countdown timing

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
function countdown() {
        setInterval(function() {
            seconds = seconds - 1;

            if(seconds < 1) {
                endGame();
            }
            else {
                if(seconds < 60) {
                    //...
                }
                $('.Timer').text(seconds);      
            }

        }, 1000);
    }
```

It calls the end game function when reaches 0.
End game function is just restarts the game with a restart button.

If i press the restart button, the seconds now reduced one by one.

```
function reset() {
        seconds = 60;           
    }
```

for the first time it works well. Seconds are reduced by one per second. But after few restarts, the seconds are reduced very quickly. it reaches zero in five to ten seconds.

```
function startGame() {
        reset();            
        countdown();
        $('.start-button').hide();
    }   

function endGame() {
        $('.start-button').show();
    }
```

Comment: where do you declare seconds variable ? Maybe this is a problem of variable scope

Comment: every time you call countdown, you add another setInterval. so it'll count down faster each time. You need to either STOP the interval, or only start it once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the count down is over you need to clear the timer, otherwise there will be multiple instances of timers running resulting in the said bahavior

```
function countdown() {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        seconds = seconds - 1;

        if (seconds < 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            endGame();
        } else {
            if (seconds < 60) {
                //...
            }
            $('.Timer').text(seconds);
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```